# If array item includes string but does not include other string then remove string

Tags: javascript

I have a big block of text which I've split by new line, so each item in the array is a line of text.

I'm looping through these lines and trying to detect where a line includes a `</mark>` but doesn't include a `<mark>`, and if this condition has been met then it removes the `</mark>` (as it's missing an opening tag).

```
final_formatted_log_split = logtext.split("\n");

for (i = 0, l = final_formatted_log_split.length; i < l; i++) {
  if (final_formatted_log_split[i].includes("<mark>") === false) {
    if (final_formatted_log_split[i].includes("</mark>") === true) {
      var removed_mark = final_formatted_log_split[i].replace("</mark>", "");
    }
  }
}

var final_formatted_log = final_formatted_log_split.join("\n");
console.log(final_formatted_log);
```

and this console log still includes  in the text where it doesn't include a

Just to be super clear, the expected outcome is the following:

if a line is like this:

```
line of text here</mark>
```

then it needs to remove the `</mark>` because it does not contain an opening `<mark>`

I suspect it is to do with the === false, but from what I've read online that is how others have used .includes to see if something does 'not include'

Comment: Can there be multiple `<mark>`s or nested ones on the same line?

Comment: @CertainPerformance althought the `replace` function should've removed duplicates as well...

Comment: OP- Can you give us an example for a text line for which your code does not work? what was before and what comes out after?

Comment: @Gibor unfortunately no, the replace function only replaces the first occurrence, if you don't specify a RegExp with **g** flag - see the second variation in the first demo: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace or on the same page under: `substr` (pattern)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with `===false`.Its working properly.To check this one you just put a `console.log` inside if block.

What you are doing here is,you are not replacing array value with modified one.So replace this line

`var removed_mark = final_formatted_log_split[i].replace("</mark>", "");`

with

`final_formatted_log_split[i] = final_formatted_log_split[i].replace("</mark>", "");`

And you can use one `if` block instead of two if block.

```
var final_formatted_log_split = logtext.split("\n");;

for (i = 0, l = final_formatted_log_split.length; i < l; i++) {
  if (!final_formatted_log_split[i].includes("<mark>") && final_formatted_log_split[i].includes("</mark>")) {
      final_formatted_log_split[i] = final_formatted_log_split[i].replace("</mark>", "");
  }
}

var final_formatted_log = final_formatted_log_split.join("\n");
console.log(final_formatted_log);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with simple `String.prototype.includes`:

```js
const arr = [
  '<mark>1</mark>',
  '2</mark>',
  '3</mark></mark>',
  '<mark>4</mark>',
]

const replaceMark = (arr) => {
  return arr.map(e => {
    if (e.includes('</mark>') && !e.includes('<mark>')) e = e.replace(/\<\/mark\>/g, '')
    return e
  })
}

console.log('original:', arr)
console.log('replaced:', replaceMark(arr))
```

This solution doesn't handle complex situations like `<mark>text</mark></mark>`, only the most basic ones.